# django-celery-beat doesn't start within supervisor just manually

Tags: django, django-celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celerybeat, ebextensions

I've installed Celery[sqs] and django-celery-beat in my Django 1.10 project.
I've trying to run them both (worker and beat) **using Supervisor on and Elastic Beanstalk instance.**

The Supervisor config is being created dynamically with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get django environment variables
celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g' | sed 's/%/%%/g'`
celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

# create celery beat config script
celerybeatconf="[program:celery-beat]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A phsite --loglevel=DEBUG --workdir=/tmp -S django --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid
directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
autostart=false
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 10

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=$celeryenv"

# create celery worker config script
celeryworkerconf="[program:celery-worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A phsite --loglevel=INFO
directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=999

environment=$celeryenv"

# create files for the scripts
echo "$celerybeatconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celerybeat.conf
echo "$celeryworkerconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celeryworker.conf

# add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  then
  echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  echo "files: celerybeat.conf celeryworker.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
fi

# reread the supervisord config
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread
# update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update
```

After which the following ebextension is running:

```
container_commands:
  01_create_celery_beat_configuration_file:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/files/celery_configuration.sh > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && chmod 744 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
  02_chmod_supervisor_sock:
    command: "chmod 777 /opt/python/run/supervisor.sock"
  03_create_logs:
    command: "touch /var/log/celery-beat.log /var/log/celery-worker.log"
  04_chmod_logs:
    command: "chmod 777 /var/log/celery-beat.log /var/log/celery-worker.log"
  05_start_celery_worker:
    command: "/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celery-worker"
  06_start_celery_beat:
    command: "/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf start celery-beat"
```

When logging-in to the Instance, and running

```
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf status
```

celery-beat is already "not started" (with an empty log file) while the celery-worker is running.
The weirdest part is that if I run it manually (e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf start celery-beat
```

It's running without errors.

Anyone has any idea how to debug it?
Why would it not load within the eb_extension while it does load later?
Maybe that has to do with the fact the Django is not up yet and am using `django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler` configuration?

Answer (score 1):

So the simple reason is, the shell script created in the eb_extension:

```
container_commands:
  01_create_celery_beat_configuration_file:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/files/celery_configuration.sh > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && chmod 744 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
```

Is created in the appdeploy/post directory and therefore runs (post deployment and basically) after the following commands are executed.
The start/restart command don't do a thing because the shell script hasn't registered those services yet. ‍♂️